# Why does this MySQL date_sub statement return wrong values?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I had a complex statement that was returning strange values and I traced it to the following line:

```
SELECT id, updated FROM status WHERE updated > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)
ORDER BY updated;
```

It returns in my case:

```
|  ID      |  updated              |
|  123173  |  2014-06-24 13:14:10  |
|  123272  |  2014-06-24 13:17:24  |
|  123273  |  2014-06-24 13:29:13  |
|  123153  |  2014-06-24 15:35:54  |
|  123231  |  2014-06-24 15:35:55  |
< Snipped a bunch of entries after 15:35:55 >
```

Interestingly, changing to INTERVAL 30 SECOND yields no differences, but INTERVAL 24 HOUR does add a few more entries.

For the record, we're using MySQL 5.1.48, and updated is type DATETIME.  The data after 15:35:54 was the expected result.

My question is what is causing this to happen, and how can I work around it?

**UPDATE**:
I have identified my own problem, and it's not a problem with MySQL.  It's a time zone problem.

The above listed entries are UTC, as that's what our application works in.  However, the actual server/system time is our local time.  The correct way of executing the code would be:

```
SELECT id, updated FROM status WHERE updated > DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)
ORDER BY updated;
```

Comment: Please run the following query : `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MINUTE) Method1,(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE Method2);` Are the results identical ???

Comment: Running that exact statement yields an error.  Running SELECT id, updated FROM status WHERE updated > (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE); returned an identical result.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MINUTE) Method1,(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE) Method2;`. I added an answer in in addtion.

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN SELECT id, updated FROM status WHERE updated > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MINUTE) ORDER BY updated` and post that output in the question.

Comment: I've found the cause and consequently the solution, and I've updated the question to reflect my findings.  I literally needed more time to figure it out.

Comment: Add your findings as an answer.